# How to create a register-like function in Emacs

Tags: function, emacs, kill

I would like to create a function using some features of the kill-ring and registers.

Basically I want to create a new mode in which <kbd>r</kbd> followed by <kbd>p</kbd> should put the paragraph at point to a list ( <kbd>r w</kbd>  should put the word at point in that list).

Then, <kbd>i</kbd> should insert whatever is in that list at point.

This is what I have currently for a register:

```
(defun Navi-register-region ()
(interactive)
(copy-to-register ?N (region-beginning) (region-end))
)
```

I am not interested in a history of the list, I just want it to replace the string in the variable with the currently selected string constantly.

**EDIT:** So this is what I have now, though it errors "wrong type argument number-or-marker"

```
(defun Navi-word-reg ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion 
          (right-word)
          (push-mark (point) t t)
          (left-word)
          (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
          (defvar bla (car kill-ring-yank-pointer))
          ; and here I would use something to remove last item from kill-ring 
              ))
```

When I try it with (`interactive "r"`) the variable contains:

```
#("bla bla bla" 0 20 (fontified t))
```

when using the function below.

```
(defun Navi-region-reg (beg end)
      (interactive "r")
      (save-excursion (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
              (defvar bla (car kill-ring))))
```

How to extract "bla bla bla"? Still...the other problem is that I want to be able to add the word at point into the variable "`bla`". That is not possible with (`interactive "r"`) right?

Comment: Maybe add a comment why to -1 the question... allowing me to improve the question.

Comment: I did not give you the -1. However, about improving: After reading your question twice, I still do not fully realize about what you are trying to archive. What exactly do you mean by list? Maybe just give an example on how exactly your functions shall behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a long time but here it is (your own extra "register/kill-ring":

```
(defun Navi-region-reg ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion (left-word 1)
          (mark-word) 
          (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
          (setq Navireg (substring-no-properties (car kill-ring)))
          (setq kill-ring (cdr kill-ring))))
```

And to insert

```
(defun Navi-insert ()
 (interactive)
 (insert Navireg)
)
```